# Cancel dispatch_async queue that is waiting for execution

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, queue

Firstly, I know that there is a lot of question already for canceling dispatch_async, and I know it was said that running queue can't be stopped.
But there is nothing posted about waiting blocks in queue.

Let say I implement something like this.

```
@property(nonatomic)dispatch_queue_t My_queue = dispatch_queue_create("something", NULL)

dispatch_async(self.My_queue, ^(void){
   // LONG TASK ONE
});

dispatch_async(self.My_queue, ^(void){
   // LONG TASK TWO
});

dispatch_async(self.My_queue, ^(void){
   // LONG TASK THREE
});
```

In new thread there will be queue with three block, one will be running, two will be waiting. How to cancel those two that are waiting?

Comment: HAve you tried NSOperation queue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317154/gcd-how-to-remove-waiting-tasks-from-serial-queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is [dispatch_suspend()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1452801-dispatch_suspend?language=objc):

> By suspending a dispatch object, your application can temporarily prevent the execution of any blocks associated with that object. The suspension occurs after completion of any blocks running at the time of the call.

```
dispatch_suspend(self.My_queue);
```

This means that the queue will execute the pending block (the first one), and will not execute the next ones. Once you get rid of the reference to the queue, it's retain count will decrease, and once it gets to zero the queue will be destroyed, along with the scheduled blocks (unless the blocks are referenced in other parts of the code).

As a side note, regarding coding style, property names should begin with a lowercase letter, and are recommended to follow the camelCase convention: `myQueue` instead of `My_queue`.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. Regarding code style, name of my queue is not really My_queue :D So I need to actually destroy queue to get rid of the blocks? Because my case is that I have very similar calls that can be called one by one. But because they are similar, there is no point that all of them are executed. So I would like that one block remove all other waiting for execution.

Comment: @MarkoZadravec the queue will be automatically destroyed when it will no longer have any references pointing to it (thanks to ARC). The other blocks will also exists while the queue exists, they won't be however executed as the queue is now suspended.

Comment: Yes, can You just add how to activate queue again.